# DeferredResult leaving hibernate session open

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm using spring DeferredResult on a http request.
The controller receives some info, make a query or two and then return the DeferredResult.

For the sake of simplicity I put a timeout on the DeferredResult and just waited for it.

```java
final RandomObj randomObj = someDAO.getSomething(someParameters);

final CustomResponse response = new CustomResponse();
response.setError("need_password");
return new DeferredResult<CustomResponse>(10L, response);
```

But for some reason Hibernate Session is not being closed after the return of after the timeout expires.

In c3p0 there is the option to kill long unreturned connections and debug the problem, and with the DeferredResult scenario I always get this after a while:

```
jul 16, 2019 10:42:26 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool removeResource
INFO: A checked-out resource is overdue, and will be destroyed: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@13b130de
jul 16, 2019 10:42:26 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool removeResource
INFO: Logging the stack trace by which the overdue resource was checked-out.
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG STACK TRACE: Overdue resource check-out stack trace.
```

I confirmed that the session is not closed by putting some breakpoints on the Session.close() method.

In other endpoints everything is normal, request comes, session open, querys, session closed, request done.

EDIT1:

Seens spring-orm don't auto close session for async things like this:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.java#L162

EDIT2:

The DAO code:
(just changed the entityname to Foo, the rest is the same)

```java
@Repository
public class FooDAOImpl extends CustomHibernateDaoSupport {
    public Foo getByEmailAndAccountId(final String email, final Integer accountId, final Integer masterCompanyId) {
        final List<Foo> list = (List<Foo>) getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("Foo.getByEmailAndAccountId",
                new String[] { "email", "accountId", "masterCompanyId" },
                new Object[] { email, accountId, masterCompanyId });
    }
}
```

EDIT3:

I think my problem is the following:
[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/WebAsyncManager.java#L376) 3 interceptors are registered, the AsyncRequestInterceptor you said above is the second one.
When the timeout trigger,[this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResultInterceptorChain.java#L71) code is executed,
 it first trigger [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.java#L218) interceptor, after that, since there is a timeout result, it is [assigned](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.java#L226) as the result.
When the iteration is over and the second interceptor (AsyncRequestInterceptor) would be run, the result of setOrExpired (because the timeout result) is true, and it break the execution of the interceptor loop.
Because of that the AsyncRequestInterceptor don't get flagged [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/AsyncRequestInterceptor.java#L111), and it does not close the session
That is the expected behavior??

Comment: Your edit is wrong... It will close the session that is the task of the `AsyncRequestInterceptor`. Generally these things come from wrong session usage/obtaining from your own code rather than framework code. Make sure you don't use `openSession` but only `getCurrentSession` and don't mess around with connections obtained outside the scope of Spring. In all of these cases your code must manage either the session or the connection if you don't you have a leak.

Comment: There is no openSession, all connections come directly from container, still trying to understand what the AsyncRequestInterceptor do.

Comment: Which connections? Please add your dao code.

Comment: I added one more edit with DAO code, really simple one, that is the only query (apart from auth, wich behaviors correctly in other scenarios) executed.

Comment: If I dont put a timeout result everything works as expect, session is closed successfully.

Comment: @M.Deinum, could you take a look at the third edit? Thanks!!

Comment: I still believe it is your code, if you think this is an error in the Spring code, please create an issue in their github with a sample reproducing this.